# CustomFieldFormat Redmine

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

I created my own CustomFieldFormat :

init.rb

```
Redmine::CustomFieldFormat.map do |fields| 
    fields.register
    MyCustomFieldFormat.new('my', :label => :label_test, :order => 1 + 0.6)
end
```

lib/my_custom_field_format.rb

```
class MyCustomFieldFormat < Redmine::CustomFieldFormat

    def format_value(value, field_format)
        "test" 
    end

    def show_value(custom_value) 
        "test" 
    end

end
```

I would like to modify the value of the field while updating. (For example, return "test" and not the value stored in the database). But nothing happens, there is always the true value in the field and not "test". Why ?

Thanks

Comment: This depends on Redmine version, which one are you using?